How to user AdditionalRequestQueryParameters metadata param in OAuth2 technical profile
Here in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-technical-profile
you can see the OAuth2 technical profile is claimed to support  AdditionalRequestQueryParameters with the following description
Extra request query parameters. For example, you may want to send extra parameters to your identity provider. You can include multiple parameters using comma delimiter.

I am trying to use this param to force google authentication page to always show account selection view by adding this metadata param
<Item Key="AdditionalRequestQueryParameters">prompt=select_account</Item>

to my TechnicalProfile metadata
<TechnicalProfile Id="Google-OAuth2">
      <DisplayName>Continue with google displayname Google-OAuth2</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ProviderName">google</Item>
        <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth</Item>
        <Item Key="AccessTokenEndpoint">https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token</Item>
        <Item Key="ClaimsEndpoint">https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">email profile</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">GET</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="AdditionalRequestQueryParameters">prompt=select_account</Item>
        <Item Key="client_id">mykey.apps.googleusercontent.com</Item>
      </Metadata>

But this doesn't have any effect.
If I instead change authorization_endpoint to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?prompt=select_account, I get the required behaviour.
So my questions are:

Is AdditionalRequestQueryParameters metadata param implemented at all
If implemented, can it be use for the described task.


I found an alternative solution without using AdditionalRequestQueryParameters. Instead you can set prompt=select_account by using an InputClaim. Add this to your Google OAuth TechnicalProfile tag:
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="prompt" PartnerClaimType="prompt" DefaultValue="select_account" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
  </InputClaims>

